Setting text break to wrapText using Pico XLSX library in C#
I'm using Pico XLS to generate xlsx file from c#. It works fine, but I'm stuck with applying a wrapText style one some of my cells.
This should be possible, as there is an enum for this: https://documentation.help/PicoXLSX/567653c2-d633-6b90-f169-fae46fab93fc.htm
PicoXLSX.Style.CellXf.TextBreakValue.wrapText

But I could not find any way how to apply this on either one of my PicoXLSX.Styles or directly on one of my cells.
PicoXLSX.Styles has a CurrentCellXf property, but I don't see how to set the TextBreakValue on this.
Any help, please?
